# How to find chat history for Skype for Linux beta

Tags: skype

Before with the old client, the chats are stored in the .skype directory, but I am not sure how to find the chat history in the new skype for linux beta.

Comment: Did you try using a data recovery software on your Skype to pull all the chats?

Comment: I wasn't aware that skype for linux beta had data recovery software, I will look into that